# how to call function from Class A in different class B function in extjs4

Tags: extjs

*Note:- i want to call ClassA function "deleteEntryInternal" in another class B within "afterRequest function. how can i call this function in other class function.*

My code is Below
//here is my Class A

```
Ext.define('WebCare.UI.OtherServicesEditor', {
extend: 'Ext.WebCare.UI.BaseEditor',
_otherservicesGrid: null,
alias: 'widget.otherserviceseditor',
title: 'Other Services',
defaultType: 'textfield',
id: 'otherservicesEditor',

deleteEntryInternal: function (isDelete) {
    this.disableForm();
    var self = this;
    var selection =     self._otherservicesGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
    if (selection.length > 0) {
        if (isDelete) {
            selection[0].data.IsDelete = true;
        }
        this.deleteServerRecord(selection[0].data, function () { });

        vent.trigger(otherServicesStore.storeId, selection[0].data);
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot call the function of a class, unless the function is static. You can only call the function on a class instance. For that, you would need an instance (`var instanceA = Ext.create('A'); instanceA.deleteEntryInternal()`)

Comment: Thanks for reply..!!!

Comment: How about [mixins](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-mixins)?

Comment: Than you, Yes its working, but when i call this  function then i am not able to get data in "self._otherservicesGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();". row data is blank, so i am able to perform action, can you please  guide me about this ?

Comment: fn: function (buttonId) {
                        if (buttonId === "yes") {
                      
                            //Ext.deleteEntryInternal(false);
                            var inst = Ext.create('WebCare.UI.OtherServicesEditor');
                            inst.deleteEntryInternal(false);

                        }
                    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call this method, you need to obtain instance of this class. And then you can call methods in that class.

**1.You can get an instance of Ext.app.Controller by**

```
var controllerInstance = appName.app.getController('appName.controller.controllerName');
controllerInstance.methodToCall();
```

where **appName** is name of your Extjs App.

**2.If your class is a view which is already rendered , you can get its instance by -**

```
var viewInstance = Ext.getCmp(viewId);
viewInstance.methodToCall();
```

where **viewId** is id of your view.

**3. Static class -** 
You can call methods of static class directly like if class MyStaticClass is static class , you can call its methods like -

```
MyStaticClass.methodToCall();
```

Answer (score -1):

It is never a good idea to cross reference class methods on any way. Although Harshal's methods will work it is just very bad app design. If your class needs to react to an event what is happening in another class then why don't you just fire an event in class A and set up a listener in class B?

Comment: But i have to follow this design. so can you give me any idea for this ?

Comment: What sort of class triggering that event? I.e. what is the definition of the class containing the afterRequest function? Is it a controller, another view?

Comment: Yes, I agree. Ideally you should not need these type of  method calls.